How to execute multiple commands in this GitHub Actions workflow job?
I am using GitHub Actions workflow for CI/CD. The main workflow uses a reusable workflow to deploy AWS CDK applications. Currently this uses just one command passed into the reusable workflow and works that way. I need to modify this setup so that I can add one more job to the main workflow which requires 2 commands to be executed back to back in the reusable workflow. In addition to calling the cdk deploy and passing in the args like I am doing here below, I also need to call npm run build just before the cdk deploy statement. How do I modify the 2 files below to make this happen?
The current main workflow with 2 jobs:
  api-deploy:
    needs: run-unit-rests
    uses: my/repo/.github/workflows/reusable_wf.yml@v1.0.1
    with:
      environment: DEV
      working-directory: app/stacks/api_layer_stack
      cdk-command: deploy
      cdk-args: app_api -c myparam1=bla -c myparam2=bla --require-approval never


  lambda-deploy:
    needs: run-unit-rests
    uses: my/repo/.github/workflows/reusable_wf.yml@v1.0.1
    with:
      environment: DEV
      working-directory: app/stacks/lambda_layer_stack
      cdk-command: deploy
      cdk-args: app_func -c myparam2=bla --require-approval never
    

The current reusable workflow (reusable_wf.yml) referenced in the main workflow above. This has one job with multiple steps.
on:
  # Reusable
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      cdk-command:
        type: string
        required: true
      cdk-args:
        type: string
        required: true
      environment:
        type: string
        required: true
      working-directory:
        type: string
        required: true

    jobs:
      run-job:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
        steps:      
          - name: Download source code
            uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
            with:
              name: app-package
    
   
          - name: Setup Python
            uses: actions/setup-python@v4
            with:
              python-version: '3.12'  
    
          - name: Install CDK
            run: npm install -g aws-cdk
    
          - name: Install Python dependencies
            run: pip install -r infra/requirements.txt
    
          - name: Install Node
            run: npm install node
    
          - name: Install TypeScript
            run: npm install -D typescript
    
          - name: Configure AWS credentials
            uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
            with:
              role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::...
              aws-region: ${{ vars.REGION }}
              role-session-name: GHA
    
  - name: Run CDK ${{ inputs.cdk-command }} for Account ${{ vars.ACCOUNT }}
    working-directory: ${{ inputs.working-directory }}
    run: cdk ${{ inputs.cdk-command }} ${{ inputs.cdk-args }}
    env:
      this_ACCOUNT: ${{ vars.ACCOUNT }}
      this_REGION: ${{ vars.REGION }}

I would prefer to keep the existing jobs as is without affecting how they run.

Seems like this would be much easier if you flipped it around and, instead of having a reusable workflow you passed scripts to, had a custom composite action the other workflows used. Then they can have as many steps as they need after the initial setup completes.

@jonrsharpe this is my first attempt at github workflows, do you have an example?

There are several examples in the docs linked above ^^, or e.g. https://github.com/textbook/take-action/tree/nodejs is a composite action.

You can support both interfaces in your reusable workflow:
jobs:
  run-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    steps:
      - name: Run CDK
        env:
          this_ACCOUNT: ${{ vars.ACCOUNT }}
          this_REGION: ${{ vars.REGION }}
        run: |
          cd ${{ inputs.working-directory }}
          if [ -n "${{ inputs.cdk-command }}" ]; then
            cdk ${{ inputs.cdk-command }} ${{ inputs.cdk-args}}
          elif [ -n "${{ inputs.run }}" ]; then               
            ${{ inputs.run }}
          else
            echo Neither cdk-command not run were provided 
          fi

Then you can mix and match the invocation style:
api-deploy:
  needs: run-unit-rests
  uses: my/repo/.github/workflows/reusable_wf.yml@v1.0.1
  with:
    environment: DEV
    working-directory: app/stacks/api_layer_stack
    cdk-command: deploy
    cdk-args: app_api -c myparam1=bla -c myparam2=bla --require-approval never


lambda-deploy:
  needs: run-unit-rests
  uses: my/repo/.github/workflows/reusable_wf.yml@v1.0.1
  with:
    environment: DEV
    working-directory: app/stacks/lambda_layer_stack
    cdk-command: deploy
    cdk-args: app_func -c myparam2=bla --require-approval never


api-deploy-multi-command:
  needs: run-unit-rests
  uses: my/repo/.github/workflows/reusable_wf.yml@v1.0.1
  with:
    environment: DEV
    working-directory: app/stacks/api_layer_stack
    run: |
      cdk deploy app_api -c myparam1=bla -c myparam2=bla --require-approval never
      # Additional commands

lambda-deploy-multi-command:
  needs: run-unit-rests
  uses: my/repo/.github/workflows/reusable_wf.yml@v1.0.1
  with:
    environment: DEV
    working-directory: app/stacks/lambda_layer_stack
    run: |
      cdk deploy app_func -c myparam2=bla --require-approval never
      # Additional commands


wont this affect how the other jobs are run.  I don't want to modify those. Sorry I didn't make that clear in the question.

Updated my answer

Thanks. Can this have the else if block so either one of my steps don't show empty. This looks like it will print the name of one step and not run anything under it and then the next step will show something run under its name based on the if condition.

GitHub Actions do not support a step selector, e.g. if/else or a switch  if: is just a condition for the step to run. Yes, you will have an "empty" step when the if: returned false. I updated the answer to eliminate that.

Thanks. In the multi-command job when you setup the title: variable, where is it getting the ${{ inputs.cdk-command }} from?

Good point - I meant to add a prep step in the reusable workflow before the actual execution that would expose title as a step output. I eliminated title in the last approach for simplicity

Ok. Do I need to export this_ACCOUNT=${{ vars.ACCOUNT }} ? can't I just use the env: this_ACCOUNT like I have in my question?

Updated answer.

thanks. I made the updates as shown above and now I get an error startup failure I think I need to make the parameters optional since they may or may not be used depending on what job is being run

Also in the else block there needs to be a statement I think. I get an error there syntax error near unexpected token fi'`

Yes, cdk-command, cdk-args and run are optional. Improved if/else.
